# Set value Entity Framework Core during OnGet

Tags: entity-framework-core

I thought this would be simple...
If I want to force a value to a column/filed before the page loads, how do I do that?

Here's the lines from the Model:

```
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Contract Value")]
    public decimal? ContractValue { get; set; } = 0m;
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name = "Contract Expended")]
    public decimal? ContractValueExpended { get; set; } = 0m;
```

And, here's what I tried using Fluent API.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
        .Property(e => e.ContractValue)
        .HasDefaultValue(0);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
        .Property(e => e.ContractValueExpended)
        .HasDefaultValue(0);
```

My bad. Here is create.cshtml.cs

```
public class CreateModel : GlobalPageModel
{
    private readonly TawdryIndustries.Data.CompanyContext _context;

    public CreateModel(TawdryIndustries.Data.CompanyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        PopulateEmployeeNamesSelectList(_context);
        PopulateCustomerNamesSelectList(_context);
        return Page();
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public Contract Contract { get; set; }
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        var emptyContract = new Contract();
        if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Contract>(
            emptyContract,
            "Contract",
            c => c.ContractID,
            c => c.ContractNumber,
            c => c.ContractName,
            c => c.CustomerID,
            c => c.ContractAwardDate,
            c => c.ContractBegDate,
            c => c.ContractEndDate,
            c => c.ContractValue,
            c => c.ContractValueExpended,
            c => c.ContractManagerID))
        {
            _context.Contracts.Add(emptyContract);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }
        PopulateEmployeeNamesSelectList(_context, emptyContract.ContractManagerID);
        PopulateCustomerNamesSelectList(_context, emptyContract.CustomerID);
        return Page();
    }
```

And, here is the razor page (create.cshtml):

```
@page
@model TawdryIndustries.Pages.Contracts.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Contract</h4>
<hr />
<form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.CustomerID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Contract.CustomerID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.CustomerNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Customer --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.CustomerID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractNumber" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractNumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractName" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractAwardDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractAwardDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractAwardDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractBegDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractBegDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractBegDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractEndDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractEndDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractEndDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractValue" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractValue" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractValue" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractValueExpended" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Contract.ContractValueExpended" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractValueExpended" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label asp-for="Contract.ContractManagerID" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Contract.ContractManagerID" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="@Model.EmployeeNameSL">
                    <option value="">-- Select Manager --</option>
                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Contract.ContractManagerID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>


<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

However, when the page is displayed (in create specifically), both of those fields are still blank. I want to force both fields to 0 when a new contract is created before the page loads.

For that matter, is there any way to set a value for a variable before a page loads?

In ASP.NET I would

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <asp:textbox id="mytext" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
    </body>
```

and:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string somevar = "This is a test";
    mytext.Text = somevar;

}
```

And the text box would contain "This is a test" when the page was displayed.

What is the equivalent in EF Core?

Thanks,
John

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing how an object is created and how it's sent to which UI.

Comment: I added the relevant pages.

Comment: Not sure what's the exact problem, since EF Core has nothing to do with "displaying pages". The only place where EF eventually comes into play is when applying whatever you give it in the database. In that regard,  remove `.HasDefaultValue(0)` fluent configuration, because contrary to what you may think, they will actually cause 0 values **not** to be sent as part of the `insert` statement, thus will have whatever the default value is set-up for the column in the table - most probably `null` since you don't seem to use migrations for maintaining the db schema.

Comment: Mayne my terminology is confused. Maybe it's MVC? Basically, I have a folder of models and folders of pages that each relate to those models. Each model has index, create, details, edit, delete pages created by the scaffolding process. Those are the "pages" I am referring to. When one of those pages is requested by the browser, how do I populate one of the fields in a page with a value before it is sent to the browser.